# Onde está o erro nas minhas perguntas?

Tags: debate, perguntas, voto-contra

Tenho recebido de 1 a 2 votos negativos nas minhas perguntas nesses últimos dias, e quem está dando os downvotes não está deixando comentário algum, aqui está a lista das perguntas que fiz nesses últimos dois dias:

1. [Como funciona a importação de bibliotecas no JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127438/como-funciona-a-importa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-bibliotecas-no-javascript)
2. [Qual é a finalidade das propriedades “id” e “name” de uma tag HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127330/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-das-propriedades-id-e-name-de-uma-tag-html)
3. [O que caracteriza a programação imperativa e funcional?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127121/o-que-caracteriza-a-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-imperativa-e-funcional)
4. [Como o navegador lida com laço infinito em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126893/como-o-navegador-lida-com-la%C3%A7o-infinito-em-javascript)
5. [Qual é o paradigma de programação usado pelo JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126886/qual-%C3%A9-o-paradigma-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-usado-pelo-javascript)

São todas referentes as tags HTML e JavaScript, o tempo médio dos votos negativos fica entre a 3 e 7 minutos após eu fazer a pergunta (não é o valor exato, porém uma pesquisa mais apurada pode revelar o valor).

Eu gostaria que a comunidade me ajudasse a descobrir o que há de errado nas perguntas, que está fazendo com que elas sejam negativadas, como não há comentários (feedback) deixados pelo usuário que está me negativando eu não sei em qual aspeto eu possa melhorar.

Nota:

> Minha intenção aqui não é desmascarar ninguém, eu valorizo muito a
>   comunidade, e eu não quero prejudicar alguém.

Comment: Eu quase marquei a terceira como duplicata. Depois de rever rapidinho as quatro primeiras são dignas de voto positivo (que eu deixei nelas), mas a quinta... A forma da pergunta parece questão de prova mal-formulada. Tirando essa última suas perguntas são boas, continue assim. Repare que suas perguntas têm pontuação positiva e você já tem algumas medalhas por isso. Ignore votos negativos quando forem uma minoria muito pequena, porque no final das contas, mesmo que você seja o cara mais brilhante da face da terra, sempre haters gonna hate.

Comment: @Renan obrigado pelo conselho :), eu sempre faço minhas perguntas pesando nos outros usuários, tanto como os que irão responder como os que estão buscando alguma solução. Em relação a ultima vou tomar mais cuidado da próxima vez para não fazer perguntas naquele modelo.

Answer (score 5):

Todas estas perguntas são boas em todos os critérios. Algumas podem até não ser nota 10, até porque quando se pergunta nem sempre é fácil fazer a pergunta da melhor forma quando não se domina o assunto, mesmo com pequenos defeitos nenhuma merce negativos, algumas talvez merece até mais positivos. As perguntas são úteis e ajudam várias pessoas, algumas estão acima da média do que é postado no site.

Negativos existem no site para serem usados. Idealmente bem usados. Claro que o critério é de cada um, mas algumas coisa não deveriam ser motivo para negativos, entre eles não gostar da pessoa, não gostar do tipo de pergunta, porque acha que a pessoa está postando só pra ganhar reputação, e coisas do tipo. A avaliação deve ser pelo conteúdo. Mesmo quando uma pergunta tem problemas muitas vezes a solução é fechá-la e não negativá-la. A negativação é para casos onde o conteúdo é ruim, vai causar problema, não vai ajudar ninguém e deve ser classificado como conteúdo negativo, potencialmente nocivo a quem for ler aquilo.

Os negativos são muito importante nas respostas para indicar se aquilo está certo ou não. Mas eles são até incentivamos mais nas perguntas, afinal não tem custo dar um negativo em pergunta, permite-se mais votos diários se forem priorizados votos em perguntas e tem medalhas que incentivam o voto nelas, incluindo os negativos. Inclusive tem critérios de remoção de perguntas baseados no fato dela estar negativada. O negativo em perguntas é importante.

Minha visão pessoa é que há até mais erros em votos positivos em perguntas do que negativos. A pessoa fica curiosa, não entende do assunto e acha que aquilo é útil, não entende o objetivo do site ou tem a visão de ser justiceiro no sentido de positivar as coisas. O positivo dado errado pode causar mais problemas que o negativo errado. O ideal que o voto errado não acontece, claro. Principalmente quando a pessoa sabe que é errado. A falta de voto para um lado ou outro pode causar efeito melhora ou piora da classificação. Para votar errado é melhor não votar, para votar certo, faça, seja positivo, ou negativo. Só pode votar certo quem conhece o assunto minimamente e está disposto gastar um tempo avaliando aquilo.

Justamente por ser um site de perguntas respostas todas elas devem ser avaliadas e classificadas. O negativo faz parte disto. Se recursar a negativar é um direito de cada um, mas não fazer quando ele é adequado, não ajuda a comunidade. Isto é o que nos diferencia do fórum. O fórum privilegia a pessoa e a comunidade por acaso é beneficiada. Aqui a comunidade deve ser beneficiada, por acaso o individuo é beneficiado junto.

Então não tem nada errado em perguntas que beneficiam a comunidade. Os negativos foram dados por maldade ou desconhecimento do assunto ou do funcionamento do site. Bem-vindo ao clube.

Answer (score -6):

Não há nada de errado com suas perguntas.

[Central de ajuda >Perguntando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Não existe pergunta errada (com exceção da gramática ou concordância ). Infelizmente alguns usuários se esquecem que um fórum é para pessoas com muita e com pouca experiência. Em geral quando alguém faz a primeira pergunta ela apenas quer uma resposta, e não se atem que pode haver uma pergunta já realizada que talvez responda a dúvida. Na minha opinião se a pessoa está perguntando ela não conseguiu identificar uma resposta e está buscando ajuda, no mínimo alguém que se propõe a ajudar não irá dar um downvote e sim começar um diálogo com que fez a pergunta a fim de obter mais elementos para que fique claro qual a dúvida em questão e assim colaborar na solução.

Avaliar significa determinar o valor, o único valor que uma pergunta pode ter é sua própria resposta, esta sim deve ser avaliada.
[Reception[edit]
Stack Overflow has received general praise for its architecture of handling questions and answers as they are regulated by the community.[34] The success of Stack Overflow has often been attributed to the fact the community itself self-regulates Stack Overflow.

Programmer 
George Olivetti criticised Stack Overflow in a study that found its policies discouraged women from being actively involved. The site encourages oneupmanship, flame-wars and down-voting which the study found makes it less likely that female users will participate. The study criticises the rewards system that the site uses. It also found instances of "gender swapping" with females adopting male or gender-neutral personas and some males masquerading as females in the belief that they will not be treated as harshly. Stack Overflow has also occasionally been criticised for maintaining a negative atmosphere for newcomers.][2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow)

Comment: Eu sempre procuro elaborar minhas perguntas com o máximo de objetividade, e concordo que as respostas são mais importante que a pergunta em si, é por isso que eu sempre procuro fazer uma boa pergunta. Entretanto, a falta de feedback por parte dos usuários que negativam é complicado, porem não me preocupo mais com isso, sempre haverá usuários dispostos a ajudar.

Comment: StackOverflow **não** é um fórum, só pra salientar, o funcionamento aqui é completamente diferente. E a pergunta, creio eu, foi no intuito de saber o que as perguntas linkadas podem ter que não estaria em conformidade com o que a filosofia do site considera "uma pergunta bem elaborada".

Comment: @Diego F 1º  No meu entendimento um site que promove o debate relativo a questões feitas por usuários pode ser chamado de fórum, mesmo que seja uma comunidade, ele exerce o papel de fórum também.
2º Dica, quando for corrigir alguém ou "salientar" sua opinião, coloque fontes que de embasamento ao que está dizendo...

Comment: @Diego F 3ª Eu sei ler, e li a pergunta e respondi segundo o meu entendimento e não segundo o seu entendimento, o usuário cita explicitamente o termo "downvote", o qual eu também já tinha notado, e que deixei a minha opinião bem clara a respeito,ou seja, na minha opinião uma pergunta bem elaborada pode ser avaliada com pontos positivos, mas nunca uma pergunta poderia ser avaliada com pontos negativos, a resposta pelo contrário sim.

Comment: [help] tudo pode ser encontrado aqui, esta é a fonte de praticamente tudo do SOPT :)

Comment: @dmcarvalho mas o problema ao meu ver é justamente esse, existem usuários que nem se quer se dão a trabalho de embasar seus comentários e principalmente os downvotes, eis o motivo de eu ser contra o downvote. ex eu respondi sua pergunta ela foi negativada mesmo tendo uma certa coerência e o pior, na sequência uma questão que eu havia feito tmb foi negativada ou seja tem pessoas que preferem ficar operando mais como juízes do que como colaboradores...

Comment: Não somos um fórum e não promovemos debates, somos um Q&A, as perguntas devem ser claras e as respostas objetivas e não podem ser opiniões, portanto não promovemos debates de nível algum. O problema não é o voto negativo, o problema é o voto negativo mal usado, o downvote usado pra apontar problemas graves é ótimo, o problema são as pessoas que usam com o inutito de tornar outra resposta evidente ou por picunhinha com o autor de uma pergunta ou resposta, todavia a maioria dos downvotes são justificaveis e não foi por falta de leitura. Esse tipo de assunto já foi debatido aqui inumeras vezes...

Comment: Veja: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Anegativo e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Adownvote ... E leia isto [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-português-é-um-fórum), no próprio [**tour**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) tem a seguinte mensagem: *Este site tem o objetivo de obter respostas. Não é um fórum de discussão. Não tem bla bla bla.* PS: estamos no META, aqui é diferente, existe um nivel tolerado de debate e o downvote aqui não afeta a reputação/score, então não leve a mal...

Comment: ...esses dois downvotes que recebeu, me parecem justos justamente pra mostrar que tem algo errado na sua resposta e meus comentários aqui só visam lhe ajudar e orientar, espero que entenda como criticas construtivas.

Comment: Assino embaixo do que o Diego e Guilherme disseram. Cada um pode até ter um opinião sobre como gostaria que o site seja, eu tenho a minha, mas é importante que todos sigam em um única direção, o que é bom para a comunidade deve ser respeitado por todos. Se cada um fizer as coisas do jeito que bem entende vira bagunça. Existe um parâmetro de como as coisas devem funcionam aqui, seja pela definição clara na central de ajuda, seja pelas discussões aqui no meta (como já foi dito, aqui sim é um local de debate do funcionamento do próprio site principal). Pode-se questionar, dar ideias, etc.

Comment: @Gulherme Nascimento A paz amigo, bom dia, 1º https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debate 2º https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rum_de_discuss%C3%A3o
Se este site não se enquadra nas definições acima, aí realmente, passo a ver um problema que parte do conceito técnico geral para aquele ponto patológico pessoal chamado egocentrismo.

Comment: @bigbow A paz, nobre cavalheiro, como pode assinar embaixo do que dizem o Guilherme e o Diego, se ambos afirma que aqui não é um fórum e não promove debate ? Como pode um lugar de "Questions and Answers" não promover o debate ? Vê como o ser humano tem uma tendência a se distanciar de todas as definições quando lhe é conveniente a sua própria definição ? Minha resposta não está errada, bem como a pergunta do usuário, mas ao invés de concordarem com alguém de baixa reputação que está correto, alguns preferem concordar com o errado apenas pela reputação, é tendencioso.

Comment: @Atodos A história nos mostra, que nem toda reputação foi construída sob o pilar do correto e justo (isto não é pessoal ou direcionado a alguém que descordou de mim, é uma reflexão, que tenta nos levar a pontos mais profundos). É um padrão, todos aqueles que tentaram se opor a um dogma estabelecido enfrentaram essa dificuldade. É difícil contradizer até mesmo os próprios conceitos, que dirá de uma comunidade... A verdade não tem dono, porém o efeito "manada" , nos mostra os perigos de avaliar ideias pela reputação de alguém do que pelo pilar do conhecimento: "A lógica !"

Comment: @MagicHat Eles já providenciaram informações suficiente para você ler e descobrir que aqui não é um fórum e recusa o debate. Perguntas devem ser objetivas, falar de fatos, não de opiniões, não deve incentivar o debate. As respostas mais ainda. Ou a resposta está certa ou errada. Em debate tudo pode estar certo. Em um site de perguntas e respostas não se coloca ideia, não não se concorda ou discorda, além do do voto. Não há turnos, não se espera a vez, a resposta tem início, meio e fim, não é aberta à discussão. Você pode discordar, mas este site é assim.

Comment: Concordo plenamente que você está se distanciando da definição porque é conveniente para você. As pessoas aqui conhecem o funcionamento do site, você claramente demonstra não conhecer e aparentemente não quer se informar sobre o assunto. Então você está sendo tendencioso, você botou na cabeça que está certo, e todas as pessoas que estão aqui discordando de você, que acabou de chegar, estão erradas. Você acabou de se declarar como dono da verdade. Você tem o dogma de achar que as pessoas estão seguindo a reputação. Não há nada que indique isto, só sua opinião completamente sem base.

Comment: Você tem todo o direito de não gostar de como este site funciona, tem o direito de dizer que não gosta, tem o direito de ir embora, só não tem o direito de proceder do jeito que bem entende. Existem regras aqui e elas devem ser seguidas. Se não gostou de alguma, tente mudá-la. Se não conseguir, paciência. Continua bem-vindo em colaborar positivamente.

Comment: @bigown não me declarei o dono da verdade, declarei que no meu ponto de vista e segundo as suas próprias informações, minha resposta está correta, pois o site em questão por ser Q&A promove debates e que o termo fórum poderia se aplicar ao Stack, em relação a reputação fiz uma observação no âmbito geral (não apenas ao Stack) e deixei claro que não está direcionado a ninguém que participou deste debate, de qualquer forma você como moderador (mesmo que não fosse) não pode afirmar  o quanto eu me informo ou não sobre determinado assunto.

Comment: @bigown Não cometa o erro de me julgar, pois até o momento eu não julguei ninguém, não falei diretamente a ninguém, todas minhas opiniões foram generalizadas e não direcionadas como você o faz agora. Mas dou por encerrado a minha participação nesta questão que tomou rumos desnecessários ou não, já retirei o que havia de bom em tudo o que foi dito e ignoro o que foge ao racional. A paz !